# Sound glitch in ubuntu 14.04 - without any stress ; lenovo G50

Tags: 14.04, sound, lenovo

i've just bought a laptop.
Changed drive to SSD, installed ubuntu ofc and here I am.
After few problems (didn't modified deep options and/or booting) i can use it more or less.

But watching video on youtube or listening to music is pain in the back.

Why?
Because approx once for minute it has very irritating 2 sec. hangs and after approx minute same thing happens.

Doesn't matter if it's youtube, or rythmbox, happens same.

My laptop Is Lenovo G50-30.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have a G50-30 with Trusty (Linux Lite 2.6) and my sound is good.
Checked in OpenTTD, VLC, SMplayer, WZ2100 and YouTube in Firefox.
Try use an LTS distro. My choice: Wait to 16.04 and install. :)

Intel HDA is installed correctly?
Please test with:

```
# dmesg | grep -i hda
# dmesg | grep -i snd
# dmesg | grep -i acpi
# lsmod | grep -i hda
```

32 or 64 bit? I use 32bit edition.